# as if you have seen the ghost/ saw the ghost

Tags: grammar

You didn’t see a ghost.

What is the matter? You look as if you _________________________

a)  …..saw the ghost?

b)  … have seen the ghost?

I have always thought that unreal imaginative events produce past tense in «as if» Clause. The keys in the grammar book say – have seen the ghost. Could you, please, explain why?

Thank you!

Comment: Yet another example of an incorrect grammar book. We say "You look as if you **had** seen **a** ghost." (_The ghost_ might be appropriate in a house reputed to be haunted by a particular ghost.)

Comment: @KateBunting i wanted to say that exact same thing as you, but if you already mentioned it, then I cant rly post my answer right?

Comment: @DialFrost - do you understand the difference between answers and comments on this site?

Comment: Yes, but its repetitive to say it **both** in the comments **and** in the answer no? @MichaelHarvey. Or did i get something wrong here :(

Comment: @DialFrost - people frequently incorporate comments of others in answers if they are helpful; it may be considered polite to give credit to the commenters. Comments should be considered temporary; they may be deleted at any time by moderators. To obtain guidance, all new members should [take the tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: ah ok ty @MichaelHarvey (ill make sure to credit Katebunting!)

Comment: @DialFrost - even in comments, it is probably better to avoid text-speak such as 'ty', and use case and punctuate correctly (e.g. '**I'll**' not **'ill'**).

Comment: @DialFrost - You didn't, in fact, say 'the exact same thing' as I did. My instinct that 'as if you **had** seen a ghost' is more idiomatic is borne out by [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=you+had+seen+a+ghost%2C+you+have+seen+a+ghost&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyou%20had%20seen%20a%20ghost%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyou%20have%20seen%20a%20ghost%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cyou%20had%20seen%20a%20ghost%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyou%20have%20seen%20a%20ghost%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 1):

You are allowed to say:

> You look as if you have seen a ghost

Unless you want so specify a specific ghost e.g. in a haunted house that is known for a specific ghost that haunts that house, then you can use the below (again credits to @KateBunting)

> You look as if you have seen **the** ghost

Using the below might be a bit odd

> You look as if you **had seen** a ghost

"have seen" is present perfect tense and you can use it, and "had seen" is past perfect tense. This is because one is describing the person's **current** appearance. Using "had" can be odd after "look" (credits to @MichaelHarvey and @JamesK for clarification!)

Below are examples of "have seen" and "had seen" (credits to @MichaelHarvey)

> Hey Joe! What's the matter? You look like [or/if] [you've/you] have just seen a ghost!

> When I saw Joe last night, he looked [like/as] if he had just seen a ghost.

Comment: 'You look as if you **have** seen ( or 'have just seen') a ghost' is perfectly normal. 'Had seen' is odd after the present 'look'.

Comment: Present perfect seems correct here.  The speaker is talking about the person's present appearance. The connection is made between the past event (seeing a ghost) and the present. so "You look as if you've seen a ghost" is a valid expression.

Comment: My bad guys thanks ill edit my post @JamesK

Comment: (1) Hey Joe! What's the matter? You **look** like [or as if] **you've/you have** [just] seen a ghost! (2) When I saw Joe last night, he **looked** like/as if he **had** [just] seen a ghost.

Comment: thanks for the examples @MichaelHarvey I appreciate the help given!

Comment: @DialFrost - a good answer does not need to be corrected by lots of comments underneath.

Comment: But they're helpful for the OP aren't they? @MichaelHarvey

Comment: @DialFrost - you need to realise this site is not simply here to answer the OP's question (although it is useful, hopefully, to them). In any case the 'help' for the OP should be in good answers worthy of upvotes as the tour makes clear.

Comment: I'm confused @MichaelHarvey, aren't answering the OP's question (helping them basically) and "helping the OP via good answers" the same

Comment: @DialFrost - you need to understand the purpose of comments, and of answers. They are different. All these comments are a bad thing. _This is not Reddit_.

Comment: @DialFrost,  
Michael Harvey, 
James K, Kate Bunting
thank you all for your help. I was initially confused by two examples "You look as if you know the answer" -  he truly knows the answer vs "You look as if you knew the answer" - untrue - he does not know the answer. Based on that i came to the conclusion that if we speak about unreal events then Past Simple should come in place. For me, seeing ghost is unreal, when we use this phrase we do not literally mean it . That is why i would put : look as if you saw a ghost. I need to do more reading on that! Thank you!